# can't check exists file in flutter but can check exists file in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

in dart
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iuC3.jpg)

in flutter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foZum.jpg)

add file in pubspec.yaml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODwsd.jpg)

I want to check exists file in flutter. Where do I need to modify the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Future<bool> assetExists(String path) async{
 try{
   await rootBundle.loadString(path);
   return true;
 } catch (e){
   return false;
 }
}
```

Then you can use the method like so:

```
String path = 'images/nocolor.png';
bool fileExists = await assetExists(path);
if (fileExists) {
   print ("have file");
}else{
   print ("on file");
}
```